# JQuery select all elements without disabled AND no readonly?

Tags: jquery

With JQuery, I need to select ALL INPUT elements with a condition:

'NOT disabled' (:disabled) 'AND' 'NOT readonly',

and then i'm gonna change css style to query result.

UPDATE: I need iterate over result in order..

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Verbosely:

```
$('input:not(:disabled):not([readonly])').each(function() {
     $(this).foo();
});
```

Or better:

```
$('input:enabled:not([readonly])').each(function() {
     $(this).foo();
});
```

**EDIT:**
From your following answer, theres a better way of doing what you want to do:

```
$('input').focus(function(e) {
    if($(this).is(':disabled, [readonly]')) {
        $(this).next().focus();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I really needed these:

```
$('input:not(input:enabled:not([readonly]))').each(function() {
 //skip focus to readonly input
    $(this).focus(function(){
        $(this).nextAll('input:enabled:not([readonly])')[0].focus();
    });
});
```

Comment: You should take a look at my updated answer. There's a cleaner way of doing that.