# getting the status of disabled buttons with JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have 7 button on a webpage. When i click on btn7, I want to check how many buttons are disabled.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-home" name= "btn-save1" id= "btn-save1"  required="required">Save</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-home" name= "btn-save2" id= "btn-save2"  required="required">Save</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-home" name= "btn-save3" id= "btn-save3"  required="required">Save</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-home" name= "btn-save4" id= "btn-save4"  required="required">Save</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-home" name= "btn-save5" id= "btn-save5"  required="required">Save</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-home" name= "btn-save6" id= "btn-save6" required="required">Save</button>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function()
{
                $(document).on('click', '#btn-save7', function(e){
                 alert('test');
})
});
</script>
```

How can I check if all buttons are disabled?

**Edit:**

I have checked these links but these are advanced and I am not that good with jQuery.
[JQuery select all elements without disabled AND no readonly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183820/jquery-select-all-elements-without-disabled-and-no-readonly)

http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/

[jQuery: Checking for disabled attribute and adding/removing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913845/jquery-checking-for-disabled-attribute-and-adding-removing-it)

Comment: FYI, you should use `$(document)` not `$('document')` and anyway here, because you are binding click event to `document`, you don't need ready wrapper

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks its corrected in original code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi CalculatingMachine,

In your example, there was no `btn-save7`, so I decided to create one. To avoid confusion to readers, I renamed it to `Count Buttons`.

First select the buttons with a disabled attribute like this `button:disabled`

Next count them by calling the `length` property.

Check out this snippet.

```js
$("#btn-save7").on("click", function() {
  $("#num-buttons").html($("button:disabled").length + " buttons are disabled");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-home" name= "btn-save1" id= "btn-save1"  required="required">Save</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-home" name= "btn-save2" id= "btn-save2"  disabled required="required">Save</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-home" name= "btn-save3" id= "btn-save3"  required="required">Save</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-home" name= "btn-save4" id= "btn-save4"  required="required">Save</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-home" name= "btn-save5" id= "btn-save5"  required="required">Save</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-home" name= "btn-save6" id= "btn-save6" required="required">Save</button>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-home" name= "btn-save7" id= "btn-save7" required="required">Count Buttons</button>

<p id="num-buttons"></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would add a class to the six buttons that you care about so you can select them by that class; I'll call it `counted`.

Then in your click handler, it's a simple selector with the `:disabled` selector you linked:

```
var disabledCount = $(".counted:disabled").length;
```

If for some reason you don't want to add the class, and if the buttons really do have the `id`s you've listed, you could use an [*attribute starts with*](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector and `not` to filter out `#btn-save7`:

```
var disabledCount = $("button[id^='btn-save']:disabled").not("#btn-save7").length;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But actually i want to check all 6 buttons are not if yes then i will redirect to other page else will show alert.

Comment: @CalculatingMachine: Well, your question says *"When i click on btn7 i want to check how many buttons are disabled"* so that's what I answered. But if you just want to know if they're **all** disabled, I'd probably use the `:enabled` selector instead and see if the count is 0.

Answer (score 1):

i would add a particular class to all the buttons you want to check (just in case you have more buttons on your site), e.g:

```
<button class="btn btn-home checkthis" name= "btn-save1" ...></button>
<button class="btn btn-home checkthis" name= "btn-save2" ...></button>
<button class="btn btn-home checkthis" name= "btn-save3" ...></button>
...
```

and then using this css class with disablced selector:

```
$(".checkthis:disabled").length
```

this gives you the amount of disabled buttons with class "checkthis"
and this would be a simple check if all buttons with class "checkthis" are disabled or not:

```
if( $(".checkthis:disabled").length == $(".checkthis").length ) {
   console.log("all buttons are disabled");
}
```